# How to remove the first dot from every line but only if it exists

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a list of subdomains and I want to remove any dot at the beginning of a line, if there is no dot at the beginning of the line, then it leaves that line untouched.

Like this example:

```
x8.ext.indeed.com
yk1.ext.indeed.com
za.indeed.com
zera.ext.indeed.com
.envoy.eastus2.qa.notjet.net
.envoy.westus.qa.notjet.net
.nomad.eastus2.qa.notjet.net
.nomad.westus.qa.notjet.net
.notjet.net
.torbit.notjet.net
artifacts.notjet.net
bamf.notjet.net
bamfdb.notjet.net
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases like this use the line-start reference `^` and the specific dot `[.]`match with your regexp constraining that to a minimum match `+`, so altogether your regex will be: `^[.]+`

I recommend `regex101.com` to experiment and try queries out too if you want to see in a highlighted way how this works: https://regex101.com/r/hW63Ab/1/

Comment: Awesome man, it works exactly as I want it to be. Thanks for the website